# MySQL Concat/Trim in Select query to check if exists in another table - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

**Table_Base**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | ACCOUNT        | 
+----+----------------+
|  1 |            100 | 
|  2 |            120 | 
|  3 |            193 | 
|  4 |            201 |
|  5 |            213 |
|  6 |            247 |
|  7 |            304 | 
+----+----------------+
```

**Table_Transform**

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | Account_Number |  
+----+----------------+
|  1 |            100 | 
|  2 |           9120 | 
|  3 |            193 |  
|  4 |           9201 | 
|  5 |           9213 | 
|  6 |            442 | 
|  7 |            589 |
+----+----------------+
```

All the entries in the ACCOUNT column have multiple spaces in front of them, so I use the TRIM() function.

I need to return all ACCOUNTS in Table_Base that DO NOT appear in Account_Number in Table_Transform, while taking into account that some ACCOUNTS appear in Table_Transform with a 9 in front of them. Therefore, the ACCOUNTS that should be returned are

```
    247
    304
```

However, with my code, it is ignoring the AND clause and returning those that appear in Table_Transform that have the 9 in front of them. What should I fix?

```
    SELECT * FROM Table_Base
    WHERE ACCOUNT NOT IN
    (SELECT Account_Number FROM Table_Transform)
    AND CONCAT(9,TRIM(ACCOUNT)) NOT IN (SELECT Account_Number FROM Table_Transform);
```

I believe I have a problem with the CONCAT query, as I cannot even get it to work by itself in a one line SELECT statement (it will still return incorrectly).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Base
WHERE TRIM(ACCOUNT) NOT IN
(SELECT Account_Number FROM Table_Transform)
AND CAST(CONCAT('9',TRIM(ACCOUNT)) AS UNSIGNED) NOT IN (SELECT Account_Number FROM Table_Transform);
```

--EDIT added `CAST` to make extra sure --

for a direct equivalency. I would use a `JOIN` statement, if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `NOT EXISTS`.  One method is:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Table_Base b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_Transform t
                  WHERE t.Account_Number = trim(b.account) OR
                        t.Account_Number = concat(9, trim(b.account)
                 );
```

For performance reasons, though, I would split this into two expressions:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Table_Base b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_Transform t
                  WHERE t.Account_Number = trim(b.account)

                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table_Transform t
                  WHERE t.Account_Number = concat(9, trim(b.account))
                 );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `Table_Transform(Account_Number)`.